# OpenLayers labels overlapped

Tags: openlayers-2

I have a problem with OpenLayers rendering close labels. When two labels are close, it will render the labels texts unreadable.

My goal is that when two labels with text overlap each other,  one could see the text clearly on a white background. So, if two labels overlap each other, one should be able to read the text of the one on top correctly.

For this I used the following characteristics:

```
pstyle.label = txt;
pstyle.fontColor = "#000000"   
pstyle.fontOpacity = 1;
pstyle.fontFamily="Arial";
pstyle.fontSize = "12 px";  //16px
pstyle.fontWeight = "bold";
pstyle.labelYOffset = -10;

pstyle.graphic = false;

pstyle.backgroundGraphic = "/ddrt_WEB/img/WhiteBackground.png";
pstyle.backgroundYOffset = 1;
pstyle.backgroundHeight = 20;
pstyle.backgroundWidth = 180;
pstyle.backgroundGraphicZIndex = 1
```

Which properties do I have to use to avoid this problems?

Answer (score 1):

Try the *labelOutlineColor* and *labelOutlineWidth* properties, example:

```
var yourStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
  'label' : '${name}',
  'fontColor' : '#222222',
  'fontSize' : '14px',
  'fontWeight': 'bold',
  'labelXOffset': 13,
  'labelYOffset': 10,
```

> ```
>  'labelOutlineColor' : "#FFFFFF", 
>  'labelOutlineWidth' : 2
> ```

```
});
```

This makes a 2 unit wide white border around the label.

Comment: What version of OpenLayers is this? I am using OpenLayers 3, & I am getting 'labelOutlineColor' does not exist in type 'StyleOptions'

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but I'm sure that this is for version 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to customize your styling. Use context in OpenLayers.Style(). See http://rndxpress.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/openlayers-custom-style-for-individual-features/ for example.

Regards,
Nas

Comment: rndxpress.wordpress.com is no longer available.

The authors have deleted this site.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a server side styling in order to avoid that complicated client side style?

Geoserver, Mapserver, ArcGIS server, they all have their own label engine that produce them in proper places and sizes, so you don't have to worry about overlaping or so... just, let those things to you map server

At the server side you'll only have to write a SLD and attach it to your layer.

Comment: I have a similar problem where my markers are moving around in real time as GPS data is received from the vehicles.  Several vehicles can be next to each other and even when one zooms all the way in the labels still overlap.  How can I use "server side styling" to avoid the labels from colliding?

Comment: Not an option for a WFS though, is it?

Answer (score -1):

I Agree with @Chan Petrelli, Do it on the server side. Check out the Geoserver Labeling notes [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-reference/labeling.html). There is a whole bunch of options that will solve this for you in a Server Side SLD file.

Cheers

Mark